# Labview 2012 Passing Dynamic data into/out of a while loop

Tags: while-loop, parallel-processing, labview

I'm trying to pass data which is continuously changed from the inside of one While loop to the inside of another While loop of a sub-vi.  The main program on the left is constantly reading new data and the program on the right is adding 1 to the new value.  My issue is that I cannot input new values to a While loop which is already running and thus my sub-vi is never updated.  I've tried a global variable ("write" from the main program control and then "read" into the sub-vi) but that doesn't work either (same result as if the main were just passing data into the sub).

I apparently don't have enough reputation to post a picture of my program but I'm basically trying to run parallel loops (almost inside each other).  Can anyone lend me an experienced hand?

Comment: It's not clear why a global variable isn't working correctly for you, but as others have said a queue or notifier is the better, more scalable solution and there's plenty of help and examples on these within LabVIEW. Use a queue if it's crucial that *every* data point gets through; use a notifier if it's only necessary for the reader to have the *latest* data point.

Comment: Thanks nekomatic!  I still have an issue of passing the queue down to a sub-vi.  Can you tell me what I need to have on the front panel of my sub-vi in order for it to accept a Queue as an input?

Comment: Once you've wired the queue refnum from `Obtain Queue` to another queue function in your main VI, you can right-click on that wire and choose `Create`>`Control`, then copy and paste the queue refnum control to your subVI. Alternatively you can wire the queue refnum to something, select that something and choose `Edit`>`Create SubVI` which will create a subVI with the required queue refnum control.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most common problem with while loops are based on lack of knowledge how exactly does the while loop work in LabVIEW.

First of all the information will be given outside the loop only if the condition terminal (right down corner of the loop) will be flagged as true.

If you want to pass the data earlier (while the loop is running) you have to choose easiest option:

1. **Use queue** (is the most common and well working). I can elaborate how this one work in practise if you want, or just try to run an example from LabVIEW help.
2. **local/shared variables** - you can define in your own library variables and pass the data by READ/WRITE option.

Please try to upload some documentation to an external server (as you are blocked here), and post a link, and then I could help you with a specific example.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I've been able to send data from inside my while loop using the QUEUE function from a main VI to a sub VI by using refnum (i.e. creating controls or indicators  for the dequeue operation and then defining them as inputs/outputs of that sub VI.  The only drawback is that it's slow.  My main program updates at 3Hz while the data is sent from the enqueue to dequeue and into by sub VI at 1/3Hz.  I'm either doing something wrong or that's just how fast it can go.  Again,  thank you all for everything.

Comment: Could you tell me why do you use while loop inside the subVI ? From what I understand You have main VI and one (or more?) subVI inside. 

The easiest way is to use just one loop outside. Of course there are some situations when this solution is not enaugh. Please send me at least screenshot and short description about how it should work.

Answer (score 2):

Help»Find Examples. Search for "queue". Pick out an example with parallel loops.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into Queues or Notifiers as means of passing data between running loops.

Comment: That may be a good way of doing it.  Is there a way to pass the notifications between VI's?  I.e. I have a main VI and a sub VI called out.  Can I notify between programs or doesn't the notification have to be within the same VI?

Comment: Create a notifier outside those 2 VIs, pass a reference to it, to those 2 VIs (started as subVIs)

Comment: "That may be a good way of doing it." -- it is, in fact, the preferred way of doing it.